# OpsHub Migration to VSTS cannot proceed. Revision count is more than 2500

Tags: opshub

OpsHub, please help. We are unable to migrate a project because we are apparently exceeding a limitation.

The message we are getting is:

> Migration cannot proceed further, because project:XXXXXX's changeset
>   or workitem revision count is individually more than 2500. This is a
>   limitation of the Free Version of OVSMU.

How can we see what work item or changeset is exceeding that count so we can fix it?

Comment: Can you share the logs under "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\logs“ folder?

Answer (score -1):

Commercial version (http://opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/) of OVSMU allows for migration of unlimited number of revisions.